# Cron job not firing

Tags: plugins, posts, wp-cron

I'm having this problem where cron jobs doens't seem to post delayed posts..

I'm using this cron job

```
wget -O /dev/null http://domain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: the cronjob will be triggered by wp itself, no need to setup this. "doens't seem to post delayed posts.." find a plugin instead. keyword: fix missed scheduled posts

Comment: Found this plugin, will report back if works.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-missed-schedule/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using your regular cron for that and it seems you are using the WP cron incorrectly in your example above. If you want to use wp cron in anything, this is the basic usage:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'wpcron_hook' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'wpcron_hook' );
}

add_action( 'wpcron_hook', 'delay_myposts' );

function delay_myposts() {
  // put your delay post codes in here
}
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron

If in any way that your WP cron is still not firing, this might be in your wp-config.php file

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', false);
```